Only one Power automate flow can be running at the same time for a Sharepoint list's item
I have a Sharepoint list and the Power Automate flow for each list's item.
I would like to know if it is possible to have only one flow executing per list's item.
I have an idea to create a field in the item, for example isFlowRunning. And check it each time a user starts the flow.
But maybe this is somehow already implemented.

Sorry, what’s the trigger?

@Skin Instant flow -  For a selected item (Sharepoint)

I know of no way natively but using your approach is possible, consider though, what happens if the flow times out of errors? It will never release the item. You’d have to manage that. Something to think about.

Per my knowledge, there is no method to limit only one Power automate flow be running at the same time for a SharePoint list item.
